# How do I use PhantomJS with Aurelia?

Tags: phantomjs, karma-runner, aurelia

When I switch from Chrome to PhantomJS I get the following errorh

```
Starting 'unit'...
03 08 2016 21:39:43.629:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9876/
03 08 2016 21:39:43.643:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
03 08 2016 21:39:44.355:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#ns0iei_Fprf487aCAAAA with id 15517298
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Expected an identifier but found 'originalDefine' instead
  at /home/xenoterracide/IdeaProjects/rpf-ui/test/aurelia-karma.js:49


{ uid: 0,
  name: 'unit',
  branch: false,
  error: 1,
  duration: [ 1, 91922852 ],
  time: 1470278384500 }
1
```

Here is the `karma.conf.js` generated by Aurelia.

```
"use strict";
const path = require('path');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const tsconfig = require('./tsconfig.json');

let testSrc = [
  { pattern: project.unitTestRunner.source, included: false },
  'test/aurelia-karma.js'
];

let output = project.platform.output;
let appSrc = project.build.bundles.map(x => path.join(output, x.name));
let entryIndex = appSrc.indexOf(path.join(output, project.build.loader.configTarget));
let entryBundle = appSrc.splice(entryIndex, 1)[0];
let files = [entryBundle].concat(testSrc).concat(appSrc);

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: [project.testFramework.id],
    files: files,
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      [project.unitTestRunner.source]: [project.transpiler.id]
    },
    typescriptPreprocessor: {
      typescript: require('typescript'),
      options: tsconfig.compilerOptions
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue just now. I 'solved' it by modifying aurelia-karma.js at line 49 from:

```
let originalDefine = global.define;
```

to:

```
var originalDefine = global.define;
```

Currently don't have time to find a root cause for this, may come back and edit later. Suspect this might be a typescript/transpiling issue with `let` compatibility.

(Node v4.4.7, Karma 0.13.22, jasmine v2.4.1, Aurelia-cli v0.17.0)